# Image crop backgroup

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, crop

I have to show camera in given frame. When ever I show this it got stretched. 
If I show the same on a full screen camera behind the frame it looks **OK** but when I take the picture it gives the full size image.I have to **crop the image only within the frame** and need help on doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the scale to fit center and set the layout params on the camera view. Something like :

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);

ImageVIew cameraView = (ImageView) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.camera, null);
cameraView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

and in the layout.xml file have something like :

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Comment: I have to Crop the image **only inside the frame visible part**.

Comment: So the scaleType would do that only for the imageView. I dint understand your comment. Could you be more specific or update your code here ?